# Vue: Async Data is not being rerendered

Tags: firebase, vue.js

Im completly new to Vue.js coming from Angular. I try to load asyncData and display it like this:

```js
<template>
    <section>
        <h1 v-for="employee in employees" v-bind:key="employee.name">    {{employee.name}}</h1>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from '../firebase.js'
import { Employee } from "../models/employee.js";
import { Entry } from "../models/entry.model.js";

export default {
    data: function() {
        return { employees: [] };
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loadEmployees();
    },
    methods: {

        loadEmployees: function() {
            db.collection('Employees').get().then(
                (snapshots) => {
                    for (const doc of snapshots.docs) {
                        const e = new Employee(doc.data().name, doc.data().worktimes);
                        e.id = doc.id
                        this.employees.push(e);
                    }
                }
            )
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

This seems like a simple thing to me but  the `v-for` won't display the data once its loaded. Is there something I need to know about vue and async data that I don't know? I couldn't really find anything helpful.

Comment: @zero298 Ups yeah your right. I tried overwriting to see If that solved my  problem but it didn't. I just forgot to correct it when posting this

Comment: You still need to assign back to the `data`'s `employees` after all the iterations though.  So put `this.employees = employees;` after the `for` loop and move the `const employees = [];` out of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the entire array of employees every iteration of `for (const doc of snapshots.docs)`.  Move the local declaration of `employees` out of the loop and reassign at the end.

```js
{
  loadEmployees: function() {
    db
      .collection('Employees')
      .get()
      .then(snapshots => {
        const employees = [];
        for (const doc of snapshots.docs) {
          const e = new Employee(doc.data().name, doc.data().worktimes);
          e.id = doc.id
          employees.push(e);

        }
        this.employees = employees;

        /*
         * As an alternative, you could just use .map()
         * which creates the new array, pushes to it,
         * and assigns all in one compact function
         */
        this.employees = snapshots.docs.map(doc => {
          const {
            name,
            worktimes
          } = doc.data();
          const e = new Employee(name, worktimes);
          e.id = doc.id;
        });
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I just answered you comment. I tried overwriting to see If that solved my problem but it didn't. I just forgot to correct it when posting this

Comment: Can you correct the original post so that we see the `const employees` declaration and the `this.employees` assignment. I don't see an obvious problem other than what this answer suggested.

Comment: That looks like it should work. My next step would be to look at the data object in VueDevTools and/or put console log messages in the for-loop to be certain it is called. Also make sure the name attribute (what is actually used in the template) is defined.

Comment: I mean, really this should just be a map operation.

Comment: @Martin Damn it, I had a little mistake in the employee constructor so my `doc.data().name` was not actually assigned to `employee.name`. Thanks for helping finding the problem.

Comment: @zero298 What do you mean by map operation? Do you mean mapping the `doc.data()` to a Employee object without having to assign each attribute "manually"? I wanted to do that but I didn't know how. Is there a good way or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Jonas I just mean using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for a more succinct function.  See my edit.